# Agrupar un grupo de datos por la fecha mas reciente

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta es la consulta que tengo:

```
SELECT 
    patients.name,
    biochemical_indicators.glucose,
    biochemical_indicators.cholesterol,
    biochemical_indicators.triglycerides,
    biochemical_indicators.uric_acid,
    biochemical_indicators.creatinine,
    biochemical_indicators.hemoglobin,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical
FROM biochemical_indicators
INNER JOIN patients 
ON biochemical_indicators.id_patient = patients.id_patient
WHERE patients.status = 1
ORDER BY 
    patients.name ASC,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical DESC,
    biochemical_indicators.id_indctrs DESC
```

Este es mi resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta marcado con la flecha roja es lo que necesito de resultado, intente con la funcion MAX() pero no me funciono.

Alguien que me puede ayudar a solucionar este problema.

Comment: Necesitas agrupar por la fecha mas reciente por cada usuario

Comment: Te pregunto, y que campos necesitas que vengan en el resultado aparte de la fecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione quitando el **ORDER BY** y lo hice con el **WHERE**

```
SELECT 
    patients.name,
    biochemical_indicators.glucose,
    biochemical_indicators.cholesterol,
    biochemical_indicators.triglycerides,
    biochemical_indicators.uric_acid,
    biochemical_indicators.creatinine,
    biochemical_indicators.hemoglobin,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical
FROM biochemical_indicators
INNER JOIN patients 
ON biochemical_indicators.id_patient = patients.id_patient
WHERE 
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical IN (
        SELECT 
            MAX(biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical)
        FROM biochemical_indicators
        WHERE biochemical_indicators.id_patient = patients.id_patient
    ) AND
    patients.status = 1
```

En la imagen que puse habia un registro con la misma fecha, pero solo es un registro por fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta, de ese modo se comprende como resuelta tu pregunta

Comment: Okay, ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo tienes que ordenar por usuario también

```
    SELECT 
        b.name,
        a.glucose,
        a.cholesterol,
        a.triglycerides,
        a.uric_acid,
        a.creatinine,
        a.hemoglobin,
        a.rgrtn_biochemical
    FROM biochemical_indicators a
    INNER JOIN patients b
    ON a.id_patient = b.id_patient
    WHERE patients.status = 1
    ORDER BY 
        a.rgrtn_biochemical,
patients.name ASC,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical DESC,
    biochemical_indicators.id_indctrs DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar poner una condición en el `WHERE` que este validando que el registro sea el que tiene la ultima fecha del usuario

```
SELECT 
    patients.name,
    biochemical_indicators.glucose,
    biochemical_indicators.cholesterol,
    biochemical_indicators.triglycerides,
    biochemical_indicators.uric_acid,
    biochemical_indicators.creatinine,
    biochemical_indicators.hemoglobin,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical
FROM biochemical_indicators
INNER JOIN patients ON biochemical_indicators.id_patient = patients.id_patient
WHERE patients.status = 1 
   AND (SELECT MAX(rgrtn_biochemical) FROM biochemical_indicators b WHERE b.id_patient = patients.id_patient) = biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical
ORDER BY 
    patients.name ASC,
    biochemical_indicators.rgrtn_biochemical DESC,
    biochemical_indicators.id_indctrs DESC
```

Comment: Gracias! por la ayuda, alcance a encontrar una solucion. :)

Comment: Creo que es similar a la tuya.

Comment: Jaja es practicamente lo mismo o muy parecido